# Make a regular expression in perl to grep value work on a string with different endings

Tags: regex, perl

I have this code in perl where I want to extract the value of `'EUR_AF'`, in this case `'0.39'`.
Sometimes `'EUR_AF'` ends with `';'`, sometimes it doesn't.
Alternatively, `'EUR_AF'` may end with `'=0'` instead of `'=0.39;'` or `'=0.39'`.

How do I make the code handle that? Can't seem to find it online...I could of course wrap everything in an almost endless if-elsif-else statement, but that seems overkill.

Example text:

`AVGPOST=0.9092;AN=2184;RSQ=0.5988;ERATE=0.0081;AC=144;VT=SNP;THETA=0.0045;AA=A;SNPSOURCE=LOWCOV;LDAF=0.0959;AF=0.07;ASN_AF=0.05;AMR_AF=0.10;AFR_AF=0.11;EUR_AF=0.039`

Code: `$INFO =~ m/\;EUR\_AF\=(.*?)(;)/`

I did find that: `$INFO =~ m/\;EUR\_AF\=(.*?0)/` handles the cases of `EUR_AF=0`, but how to handle alternative scenarios efficiently?

Comment: You could make the `;` optional with a `?` or you could make the `0` optional with a `?`. Alternatively you could pull all numbers after the `=`. e.g. `EUR_AF=[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract one value:

```
my ($eur_af) = $s =~ /(?:^|;)EUR_AF=([^;]*)/;
```

```
my ($eur_af) = ";$s" =~ /;EUR_AF=([^;]*)/;
```

Extract all values:

```
my %rec = split(/[=;]/, $s);
my $eur_af = $rec{EUR_AF};
```

Comment: I think you want `my %rec = split /[=;]/, $s;` --- i.e., without the limit.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Actually, I was going for `map { split(/=/, $_, 2) } split /;/, $s`, but the simpler solution I had orignally should be good enough.

Comment: The best solution is `/(?:^|;)EUR_AF=([^;]*)/` because it will handle also the case of `1.00` or `0.039` properly; and the answer will be than `1.00` or `0.039` and not `0` or `.039`. Thanks!

Comment: In other words, it gets the entire field, no matter what it is. I also agree that's the correct approach (perhaps obviously). If any validation is to be done, it should be done independently afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

This regex should work for you: `(?<=EUR_AF=)\d+(\.\d+)?`
It means

`(?<=EUR_AF=)` - look for a string preceeded by `EUR_AF=`

`\d+(\.\d+)?` - consist of a digit, optionally a decimal digit

EDIT: I originally wanted the whole regex to return the correct result, not only the capture group. If you want the correct capture group edit it to `(?<=EUR_AF=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Comment: Must simpler: `EUR_AF=\d+(\.\d+)?` That needless lookbehind just slows things down.

Comment: `(...)?` doesn't make any sense. I think you mean `(?:...)?`. Speaking of captures, the correct capture is missing. Finally `(?<=;EUR_AF=)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` can be simplified and sped up by simply removing the lookbehind: `;EUR_AF=(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`. Simplified even further: `;EUR_AF=([^;]*)`

Comment: Actually `EUR_AF=\d+(\.\d+)? ` is not a solution because you'd end up with `.039` or in the case of `EUR_AF=1.00` with `.00`.

Comment: @SanderW.vanderLaan I was talking about the whole regex result, not only the first capturing group. And in those situations it returns proper results.

Comment: @ikegami The `(..)?` is correct, as in the examples provided by the OP, there might be a case of 0.45 or 0 without any digits after coma

Comment: @Xyzk, You could also argue that `$x * do { $y + $z }` is correct, but it's really not. Just like `$x * ( $y + $z )` would be correct here, you should have used `(?: ... )?` instead of `( ... )?` as I previously mentioned. It will handle 0.45 and0 without any digits just as well.

Comment: @Ikegami Sorry I misread your comment to be "(...)? doesn't make any sense. I think you mean (?:...)" , didn't notice the `?` at the end. You are right in general, I tried to avoid capture groups because I had some people on this website ask for non-capture group reliant regexes

Answer (score -3):

I have found the answer. The code:

`$INFO =~ m/(?:^|;)EUR_AF=([^;]*)/`

seems to handle the cases where `EUR_AF=0` and `EUR_AF=0.39`, ending *with* or *without* `;`. The resulting `$INFO` will be `0` or `0.39`.